# Reading in File line by line w/ Bash

Tags: bash, unix, while-loop, line-by-line

I'm creating a bash script to read a file in line by line, that is formatted later to be organised by name and then date. I cannot see why this code isn't working at this time though no errors show up even though I have tried with the input and output filename variables on their own, with a directory finder and export command.

```
export inputfilename="employees.txt"
export outputfilename="branch.txt"
directoryinput=$(find -name $inputfilename)
directoryoutput=$(find -name $outputfilename)
n=1

if [[ -f "$directoryinput" ]]; then
     while read line; do
         echo "$line"
         n=$((n+1))
     done < "$directoryoutput"
 else
    echo "Input file does not exist. Please create a employees.txt file"
 fi
```

All help is very much appreciated, thank you!
NOTE: As people noticed, I forgot to add in the $ sign on the data transfer to file, but it was just in copying my code, I do have the $ sign in my actual application and still no result

Comment: `done < "directoryoutput"` should probably be `done < "$directoryoutput"` (it was missing the dollar sign). You can toss these shell scripts into shellcheck.net and it's pretty good at helping to find issues like this. In this case it highlights that 4th line and notes that the variable is loaded, but never used.

Comment: Much safer to use `find . -name "$inputfilename" -print -quit`, where you're guaranteed to only find one file, vs having multiple names concatenated together in your variable, if you **must** use `find`

Comment: BTW, the [original indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53381474/1) here is **extremely** confusing. Why does the `do` move back to outside the `while` loop? Why are the contents of that loop not indented? I'm taking the liberty of revising it to follow the code flow; feel free to roll back if that's too heavy-handed, but please *do* avoid outdenting symbols that are part of a loop to an indentation level preceding that loop.

Comment: (Also, the `.` in `find . -name` is suggested above for portability reasons: Being able to leave it out is a GNUism, but doesn't work in versions of `find` that hew more closely to the baseline POSIX specification).

Answer (score 1):

> Reading in File line by line w/ Bash

The best and idiomatic way to read file line by line is to do:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  // parse line
  printf "%s" "$line"
done < "file"
```

More on this topic can be found on [bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

However don't read files in bash line by line. You can (ok, almost) always not read a stream line by line in bash. Reading a file line by line in bash is extremely slow and shouldn't be done. For simple cases all the unix tools with the help of `xargs` or `parallel` can be used, for more complicated `awk` and `datamesh` are used.

> `done < "directoryoutput"`

The code is not working, because you are passing to your while read loop as input to standard input the content of a file named `directoryoutput`. As such a file does not exists, your script fails.

> `directoryoutput=$(find -name $outputfilename)`

One can simply append the variable value *with newline appended* to a read while loop using a HERE-string construction:

`done <<< "$directoryoutput"`

> `directoryinput=$(find -name $inputfilename)`
>   `if [[ -f "$directoryinput" ]]`

This is ok as long as you have only one file named `$inputfilename` in your directory. Also it makes no sense to find a file and then check for it's existance. In case of more files, find return a newline separated list of names. However a small check `if [ "$(printf "$directoryinput" | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]` or using `find -name $inputfilename | head -n1` I think would be better.

> ```
> while read line;
>    do
>       echo "$line"
>       n=$((n+1))
>   done < "directoryoutput"
> ```

The intention is pretty clear here. This is just:

```
 n=$(<directoryoutput wc -l)
 cat "directoryoutput"
```

Except that `while read line` removed trailing and leading newlines and is IFS dependent.

Also always remember to quote your variables unless you have a reason not to.

Have a look at [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which can find most common mistakes in scripts.

I would do it more like this:

```
inputfilename="employees.txt"
outputfilename="branch.txt"

directoryinput=$(find . -name "$inputfilename")
directoryinput_cnt=$(printf "%s\n" "$directoryinput" | wc -l)
if [ "$directoryinput_cnt" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Input file does not exist. Please create a '$inputfilename' file" >&2
   exit 1
elif [ "$directoryinput_cnt" -gt 1 ]; then
   echo "Multiple file named '$inputfilename' exists in the current path" >&2
   exit 1
fi

directoryoutput=$(find . -name "$outputfilename")
directoryoutput_cnt=$(printf "%s\n" "$directoryoutput" | wc -l)

if [ "$directoryoutput_cnt" -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Input file does not exist. Please create a '$outputfilename' file" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$directoryoutput_cnt" -gt 1 ]; then 
   echo "Multiple file named '$outputfilename' exists in the current path" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cat "$directoryoutput"
n=$(<"$directoryoutput" wc -l)
```

Comment: `printf "$directoryinput"` would be better written as `printf '%s\n' "$directoryinput"`, so you aren't treating your filename (with arbitrary contents) as a format string. (Also, a trailing newline is needed to properly terminate a line of content on UNIX; [POSIX explicitly directs `wc -l` to count the number of newlines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html#tag_20_154), so content with no trailing newline is ignored).

Comment: Though the file exists, the code doesn't believe it does and returns the "Input file does not exist. Please create a '$inputfilename' file". I tried also putting dollar signs on the initialisation of the inputfilename and outputfilename variables. The rest of it looks good though, thanks!

Comment: @SamThompson you are right I made a typo. When counting the number of results I am missing one trailing newline, so we need to do like as Charles suggested, `printf "%s\n" "$...." | wc -l`. Without the `\n` it counts zero, even when one file exists :/ I forgot that command substitution `$(...)` removes trailing newlines. I've edited the answer. Alternatively with bash you can `$(<<<"$..." wc -l)` which will result in the same.